# Python/Pyodbc/SQL - Updating a table and setting a field to a CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to use pyodbc to update an existing  MS Access database table with a very long multiline string. The string is actually a csv that has been turned into a string.

The query I am trying to use to update the table is as follows:

```
          query = """
                  UPDATE Stuff 
                  SET Results = '{}'
                  WHERE AnalyteName = 
                  '{}'
                  """.format(df, analytename)
```

The full printed statement looks as follows:

```
UPDATE Stuff
SET Results = 
'col a,col b,col c,...,col z,
 Row 1,a1,b1,c1,           
 ...,...,...,...,
 Row 3000,a3000,b3000,c3000'
WHERE AnalyteName = 'Serotonin'
```

However this does not seem to be working, and I keep getting the following error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement. (-3503) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Which I assume is due to the format of the csv string I am trying to use to update the table with.

I have tried using `INSERT` and inserting a new row with the csv string and other relevant information and that seems to work. However, I need to use `UPDATE` as I will eventually be adding other csv strings to these columns. This leads me to believe that there is A) Something is wrong with the syntax of my `UPDATE` query (I am new to SQL syntax) or B) I am missing something from the documentation regarding `UPDATE` queries.

Is executing an `UPDATE` query like this possible? If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @HansUp The question has been updated with a print statement that represents what the query looks like.

Comment: @HansUp I did not know that actually, thanks. That's not the name of my table in the query, I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else wants to use this.

It turns out what I was missing was brackets around the table column fields from my UPDATE statement. My final code looked something like this.

```
csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
name = 'some_name'
query = """
        UPDATE Stuff 
        SET 
            [Results] = ?
        WHERE 
            [AnalyteName] = ?
        """
self.cursor.execute(query, (csv, name))
```

I've seen several other posts here where brackets were not around the column names. However, since this is MS Access, I believe they were required for this query, or rather this specific query since it included a very long strong in the `SET` statement.

I welcome anyone else here to provide a more efficient method of performing this task or someone else who can provide more insight into why this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It would be determined by the table's field type.
For large amounts of text you'd need a blob field in your database table.
A blob field will store binary info so using blob will not 'see' illegal characters.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you mind elaborating on how I would go about doing something like this?

Comment: You would need to add a field to your table which is a  BLOB field type. Then you save the  very long multiline string into the blob field. You can then get the data from the BLOB field using a query.